# Angular Http Observable doesn't update

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

Hey Guys i wrote a little backend which returns some data. Now i want to fetch this data with Angular Http and show new values when i post them in the backend. So the first thing that came to my mind were Observables but currently i can fetch the data onInit but when Posting new Data to the Backend (currently just via Postman) the Fetched data wont update. So if this is the wrong approach tell me how to do this please. Below is my code i used so far:

App Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import {WeaponServiceService} from './weapon-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  weaponTypesarr: IweaponsTypes [] = [
    {name: 'Nahkampf', value: 'melee'},
    {name: 'Fernkampf', value: 'ranged'},
    {name: 'Spezial', value: 'special'},
  ];
  meleeTypesarr: IweaponsTypes [] = [
    {name: 'Klingenwaffen', value: 'klinge'},
    {name: 'Messer', value: 'messer'},
    {name: 'Dolche', value: 'dolch'},
    {name: 'Äxte/Beile', value: 'axt'},
    {name: 'Speere/Stäbe', value: 'speer'},
    {name: 'Stumpfe Hiebwaffen', value: 'stumpf'}
  ];
  rangedTypesarr: IweaponsTypes [] = [
    {name: 'Bogen', value: 'bogen'},
    {name: 'Armbrust', value: 'armbrust'},
    {name: 'Wurfwaffe', value: 'wurfwaffe'},
    {name: 'kleine Schusswaffe', value: 'gun-litte'},
    {name: 'große Schusswaffe', value: 'gun-big'}
  ];
  specialTypesarr: IweaponsTypes [] = [
    {name: 'Exotische Waffen', value: 'exotics'},
    {name: 'Granaten und Exoplosive', value: 'grenade'}
  ];
  rForm: FormGroup;
  post: any;
  weaponName = '';
  weaponType= '';
  impairment= '';
  special= '';
  results: Observable<any>;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder , private weaponService: WeaponServiceService) {
    this.rForm = fb.group({
      'weaponName' : [null, Validators.required],
      'weaponType': [null, Validators.required],
      'impairment': [null, Validators.required],
      'special': [null, Validators.required]
    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
     this.results = this.weaponService.getWeapons();
     this.results.subscribe(data => {console.log(data); });
  }

  generateWeapon(weaponData) {
    this.weaponName = weaponData.weaponName;
    this.weaponType = weaponData.weaponType;
    this.impairment = weaponData.impairment;
    this.special = weaponData.special;
    console.log(weaponData);
  }

}


export interface IweaponsTypes {
  name: string;
  value: string;
}
```

WeaponServiceService (didnt knew it calls it service by its own :D):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class WeaponServiceService {

  constructor( private http: HttpClient) { }

  getWeapons() {
    return this.http.get('http://192.168.178.48:3000/getWeapons').map(data => {
      return(data);
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
  }

  createWeapon(weaponData2: any) {
    return this.http.post('http://192.168.178.48:3000/createWeapon', weaponData2)
    .map(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {WeaponServiceService} from './weapon-service.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [WeaponServiceService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and last but not least the corresponding HTML but currently i just try to log all the values.

```
<div *ngIf="!name; else forminfo">
  <form [formGroup]="rForm" (ngSubmit)="generateWeapon(rForm.value)">
        <h1>Generate Weapon</h1>
        <label for="WeaponName">WeaponName</label>
        <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="weaponName" formControlName="weaponName" id="WeaponName">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="WeaponGroup">Weapon Group</label>
                <select class="form-control" #weaponTypeSelektor formControlName="weaponType" id="WeaponGroup">
                    <option> Select a Type</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let types of weaponTypesarr" [value]="types.value">{{types.name}}</option>
                </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="weaponTypeSelektor.value == 'melee'">
              <label for="WeaponTypeMelee">Weapon Type</label>
                  <select class="form-control" formControlName="weaponType" id="WeaponTypeMelee">
                      <option *ngFor="let types of meleeTypesarr" [value]="types.value">{{types.name}}</option>
                  </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" *ngIf="weaponTypeSelektor.value == 'ranged'">
                <label for="WeaponTypeRanged">Weapon Type</label>
                    <select class="form-control" formControlName="weaponType" id="WeaponTypeRanged">
                        <option *ngFor="let types of rangedTypesarr" [value]="types.value">{{types.name}}</option>
                    </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group" *ngIf="weaponTypeSelektor.value == 'special'">
                  <label for="WeaponTypeSpecial">Weapon Type</label>
                      <select class="form-control" formControlName="weaponType" id="WeaponTypeSpecial">
                          <option *ngFor="let types of specialTypesarr" [value]="types.value">{{types.name}}</option>
                      </select>
                </div>
        <label for="impairment">Beeinträchtigung</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Beeinträchtigung" formControlName="impairment" value="" id="impairment">
        <label for="special">Spezial</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Spezial" formControlName="special" value="" id="special">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit Form" [disabled]="!rForm.valid">
  </form>

  <div  *ngFor="let item of results | async"> {{item.weaponName}} </div>
</div>

<ng-template #forminfo>
  <div class="form-container">
    <div class="row columns">
        <h1>{{ name }}</h1>

        <p>{{ weaponType }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

So just to be clear. AppComponent starts and fetched  initial data. I post Data into the Db with postman. App Component doesn't recognize new Value.

Comment: where are you subscribing?

Comment: I thought the best would be OnInit isn't it?

Comment: Does console.log(data) log the data in the console ?

Comment: Well where are you calling `createWeapon`? Nowhere? Also after that you need to refetch the data.

Comment: I think you should reread the Text

Comment: Well, what I am I missing, you say that your data won't update, I see no attempt in your code to update it?

Comment: I thought Observables would do that because they „observe“ the backend but i think that was just wrong. So do you have an idea how such a livereload Feature would be implementable?

Answer (score 0):

Change these lines in the Service.

```
getWeapons() {
return this.http.get('http://192.168.178.48:3000/getWeapons').map(data => {
  return data.json();
}
```

And Change these lines in the AppComponent

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.results = this.weaponService.getWeapons();
 //delete this line ---> this.results.subscribe(data => {console.log(data); });
}
```

since you are using the async pipe you dont need to subscribe.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Does this really change the Loading of Data in Real Time because i already log the Data. And it is already sent as json

Comment: Did the log show a json object or a response type data ?

Comment: Since you mentioned about component not recognizing the object.
You can bypass the assigning of observable type to results.It can be avoided.

Comment: Guys the Problem isnt that the Data isnt showing. The Problem is that when the Data on the backend Changes the Data on the frontend doesnt Update.

Comment: I think i get you now, Your code seems pretty solid...

You made changes in the backend , then you reloaded your app 
but your results wont show on the page...am i right...?
hmm..well if thats the case 
console logging is what i would do 
and thats what you have done as well...
please do post in your answer..

Comment: The Data shows when i reload but i thought that it would be possible to do something like a livereload.

Comment: So reload the Data without the User noticing a reload

Comment: Oh haha...finally i get it....but if you get a way around it... i would love to know how to do it...that would be a wonderful feature to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on:

- Angular CLI: 13.1.4
- Node: 17.3.0
- Package Manager: npm 8.3.0

I know I don't have the best answer but one which works (at least).
Maybe it helps someone to continue further   ;-)

I fetched the data once in the **component's ngOnInit** as well as in a **function** which pulls the database data after a defined interval/time has passed.

```js
  data: any;
  baseUrl = 'foo_URL';
  fetchInterval: 3000;   // 3 Seconds

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  // First Fetch
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get(this.baseUrl)
    .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
    .subscribe((fooData) => {
      this.data = fooData;
    })
  }

  // Interval Fetch
  setInterval: any = setInterval(() => {
    this.http.get(this.baseUrl)
    .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
    .subscribe((fooData) => {
      // Compare for view update
      if (JSON.stringify(fooData) !== JSON.stringify(this.data)) {
        console.log('New stuff -> update view')
        this.data = fooData;
      }
    });
  }, fetchInterval)

  // Shield Memory Leakeage after Component is deleted
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }
```

This is generally a bad approach as ..

1. .. data is pulled although there is no update the data.
2. .. data may be pushed towards the view without any need (fixed).
3. .. the interval is (mostly) barely adjustable to fit the need of both sides, Client & Server.

It is recommended to at least check changes in the data before updating the view with the same data.
Maybe even offer an API which only serves a checksum before pulling the whole dataset.

Last:
The more advanced solution would be a two-way-binding.
Once an API is called which changes the data, angular gets an update for the backend. For this kind of solution you might want to take a look at socket.io ... ;-)